# Script to test C++ programs

Tags: c++, testing, command-line, command-prompt

I want to write a script (Windows 10) which will be testing my program.
I have not found any suitable answer so I decided to open my own question.

I have files with input and output for my program eq.:

stud1.txt and stud1_out.txt alternatively.

My C++ program reads input from console (std::cin).

I know how to compare files (FC command) and how to run program from command line, but I have no idea how to pass on input data to a program which reads data using std::cin and then write it into the file to be able use FC command.

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Faking standard input on the Windows command line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15994824/faking-standard-input-on-the-windows-command-line)

Answer (score 0):

Use `<` to pass file contents to the STDIN of a console program, e.g.:

```
console_prog.exe <input.txt
```

More details: [Using command redirection operators](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/redirection.mspx?mfr=true)

Comment: @pjdev: use `>`. Sample: `console_prog.exe >output.txt`

Comment: You also can combine both redirectors: `console_prog.exe <input.txt >output.txt`. And even do more useful tricks. Please see the article I referenced.